# Removing a mailbox does not remove it from the get-mailboxstatistics

Tags: exchange-2010, mailbox

I used get-mailboxstatistics to get a list of mailboxes on the server.

I then manually removed one of the mailboxes using:

Use the EMC to remove a mailbox

1. In the console tree, navigate to Recipient Configuration > Mailbox.
2. In the result pane, select the mailbox you want to remove.
3. In the action pane, under the name of the mailbox, click Remove.
4. A warning appears asking, Are you sure you want to remove 'mailbox name'? Click Yes to remove the mailbox.

Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb125192(v=exchg.141).aspx

When I re-ran the get-mailboxstatistics command, the mailbox I removed, still came up in the list from the statistics.

Why is that and how do I properly remove a mailbox?

Answer (score 1):

The mailbox will still be retained for a period of time based on your Mailbox Retention settings.  Until that time, the mailbox is only Soft Deleted.  You can force a mailbox to be deleted using the [`Remove-StoreMailbox`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff829913.aspx) cmdlet.

Here is some more information:

- [Permanently Delete a Disconnected Mailbox](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg181092(v=exchg.141).aspx)
- [Understanding Disconnected Mailboxes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232039(v=exchg.141).aspx)
- [How to Configure Deleted Mailbox Retention](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125047(v=exchg.80).aspx)